# rabbitmq/rabbitmq _erlang Running continuously or every time I enter a command

Tags: magento, rabbitmq, centos

I am trying to set up a LAMP stack on lightsail (AWS EC2) with CentOS 8, designed to host Magento 2 open source.

I have tried to install all the prerequisites according to Adobe docs.

One requirement seems to be rabbitmq.

I have successfully installed it, but every time I enter any commands now it processes 4 lines of rabbitmq code:

```
[centos@ip-172-26-4-213 ~]$ sudo dnf update
//i put a space here for clarity of this Q
rabbitmq_erlang                                 328  B/s | 833  B     00:02    
rabbitmq_erlang-source                          349  B/s | 819  B     00:02    
rabbitmq_server                                 414  B/s | 833  B     00:02    
rabbitmq_server-source                          423  B/s | 819  B     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I guess something is wrong? How can I fix this?

Maybe I don't need to have rabbitmq at all — I don't really know what it does or maybe I need to pause/stop it.

---

Alternatively, I'm wondering if I should give myself a head start and use an EC2 instance and a Bitnami Magento build, at least this would probably work. I'd be on Debian, and I guess that's fine.

Comment: centos@ip-172-26-4-213 ~]$ sudo dnf update rabbitmq_erlang 328 B/s | 833 B 00:02 -- this is 2 separate lines in the shell

Answer (score 0):

Comment the rabbitmq repo form  **/etc/yum.repos.d/***
and then run again

```
sudo dnf update
```